# Maven: No primary artifact to install, installing attached artifacts instead

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a *parent* Maven POM that looks like this (the oss-parent can be seen [here](https://raw.github.com/skunkiferous/oss-parent/master/pom.xml)):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.blockwithme</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.blockwithme</groupId>
    <artifactId>xtend-contrib-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <inceptionYear>2013</inceptionYear>
    <name>Xtend Contrib Parent</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtend.lib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtend.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>base</module>
        <module>examples</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

With a child "base" POM that looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.blockwithme</groupId>
        <artifactId>xtend-contrib-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>xtend-contrib-base</artifactId>
</project>
```

It creates and install the child Jar in the local repo. But I would like to install the source and/or javadoc too. So I add this to the *parent* POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

But if I do that, the source and javadoc get installed, but the compiled code jar *stops being installed*, which makes no sense to me. Maven gives this warning:

```
[INFO] No primary artifact to install, installing attached artifacts instead.
```

Which does *not* appear, if I do not try to get the source installed. Adding the maven-jar-plugin plugin does not help. Nor does adding "<packaging>jar</packaging>" to the child POM.

Comment: what is the command you are using to install? is it: mvn install?

Comment: mvn clean install *in the parent directory*. (I *always* do "clean"; I which it was default)

Comment: does it create a jar when you use: mvn clean package from the parent directory?

Comment: Yes, "mvn clean package" says: "Building jar: D:\GithubPublic\xtend-contrib\base\target\xtend-contrib-base-0.0.3.jar" (and so does "mvn clean install") But of course, it doesn't go in the local repo, then.

Comment: i see you're using the version 2.4 of the maven-install-plugin, can you try using 2.5.1 just to exclude that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change a goal for the source plugin from `jar` to `jar-no-fork`. With `source:jar` goal as part of the lifecycle, Maven will re-run all of the goals bound to generate-sources and its predecessors. My assumption is that there is a clean executed somewhere during that loop, erasing the main jar file. In contrast, `jar-no-fork` will not run the bound goals again.

Plugin configuration should therefore look like

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That configuration did *not* help, but it *was* the auto-clean, so removing it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it's trying to do that in the parentPom.  I would not define the common plugins in your parentPom.  In your parentPom, I would define the plugins (with their versions) in the pluginManagement section of the POM (not the plugins section).  Then, in each child, state which plugins are used (without the version in the declaration).  This will provide more control.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work (with or without reference to the maven-jar-plugin).