# Maven build with jenkins for scala spark program : "No primary artifact to install, installing attached artifacts instead

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project with multiple scala spark programs, while I run mvn install through eclipse I am able to get the correct jar generated which is used with spark-submit command to run.

After pushing the code to GIT we are trying to build it using jenkins, as we want to automatically push the jar file to our hadoop cluster using ansible.
We have jenkinsfile with build goals as "compile package install -X".

The logs show that-

```
[DEBUG](f)artifact = com.esi.rxhome:PROJECT1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

[DEBUG](f) attachedArtifacts = [com.esi.rxhome:PROJECT1:jar:jar-   with-dependencies:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, com.esi.rxhome:PROJECT1:jar:jar-with-dependencies:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

[DEBUG]   (f) createChecksum = false

[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
  url: file:///home/jenkins/.m2/repository/
layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar

[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = /opt/jenkins-data/workspace/ng_datahub-pipeline_develop-JYTJLDEXV65VZWDCZAXG5Y7SHBG2534GFEF3OF2WC4543G6ANZYA/pom.xml

[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false

[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false

[DEBUG] -- end configuration --

[INFO] **No primary artifact to install, installing attached artifacts instead**
```

I saw the error in the similar post -

[Maven: No primary artifact to install, installing attached artifacts instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848214/maven-no-primary-artifact-to-install-installing-attached-artifacts-instead)

But here the answer says - Remove auto clean, I am not sure how to stop that while jenkins is building the jar file.

Below is the pom.xml-

```
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>com.esi.rxhome</groupId>
                <artifactId>PROJECT1</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <description>RxHomePreprocessing</description>
                <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
                <licenses>
                    <license>
                        <name>My License</name>
                        <url>http://....</url>
                        <distribution>repo</distribution>
                    </license>
                </licenses>

                <properties>
                    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
                    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <scala.version>2.10.6</scala.version>
                    <scala.compat.version>2.10</scala.compat.version>
                </properties>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                        <version>${scala.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Test -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>4.11</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.16</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.4</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1000.2.6.0.3-8</version>
                    </dependency>


                    <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
            </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
            </dependency> -->


                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.3</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>

                <build>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
                    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
                            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.2.0</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <args>
                                            <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                                            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                                        </args>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.18.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <useFile>false</useFile>
                                <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                                <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
                                <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                                    <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>2.4</version>
                                          <configuration>
                                                <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
                                                </configuration>
                                     <executions>
                                     <execution>
                              <goals>
                              <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        </execution>
                        </executions>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptorRefs>
                                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                </descriptorRefs>
                                <archive>
                                  <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.esi.spark.storedprocedure.Test_jdbc_nospark</mainClass>
                                  </manifest>
                                </archive>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                              <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                              </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                          <version>3.0.0</version>
                          <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                          </configuration>
                        </plugin>

                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </project>
```

I tried specifying

1 -" jar " for packaging in pom.xml.

2 -changing the maven goals to -

"install"

"clean install"

"compile package install"

But above tries did not help get rid of the message and jar created was of no use.

When I try to execute the spark submit command-

```
            spark-submit  --driver-java-options -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/EH2524/tmp --conf spark.local.dir=/home/EH2524/tmp --driver-memory 2G --executor-memory 2G --total-executor-cores 1 --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 10 --class com.esi.spark.storedprocedure.Test_jdbc_nospark  --master yarn  /home/EH2524/PROJECT1-0.0.1-20171124.213717-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
            Multiple versions of Spark are installed but SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is not set
            Spark1 will be picked by default
            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esi.spark.storedprocedure.Test_jdbc_nospark
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
                    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:175)
                    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:703)
                    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
                    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
                    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
                    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Here, Test_jdbc_nospark is a scala object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message was because of the maven-jar-plugin having the  as true. Once i removed this, the build is not giving the message "No primary artifact to install, installing attached artifacts instead"

The empty jar was getting created because of incorrect  path in pom.xml

Intitally-

```
    <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
```

As jenkins was building through code in git and the pom was inside the project folder.

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>folder_name_in_git/src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but your `maven-jar-plugin` configuration looks suspicious.  Normally, the execution would specify a phase, as in

```
  <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>jar</goal>
    </goals>
```

(from [this example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html)).  Perhaps omitting that is causing your default jar not to be built?  Certainly the error message sounds like your default jar is not being built, but you didn't actually say so.

Comment: This message was because of the maven-jar-plugin having the 
<skipifempty> as true. Once i removed this, the build is not giving the message "No primary artifact to install, installing attached artifacts instead"

But another issue here is that the jar(primary artifact) created is not having the required scala objects, hence i am not able to run the scala spark program. The jar created is of size 3kb only, also just to give out more information when I run maven install in eclipse the jar created is correct and I am able to run the scala spark program.

Comment: Digging in further, I see that Jenkins is printing the message, No source to compile which leads to the creation of an empty jar. 




? (`[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile )

     @   PROJECT1 --- [INFO] No sources to compile`?)
Trying to see why it is not able to get the sources to compile.
@Joe

Comment: Can't help on the Eclipse front (I use IntelliJ), but it sounds like your Eclipse project is somehow not using the default configuration used by Maven.